# Matrix multiplication order, and real number multiplication order.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If a, b, c and d are real numbers, I would probably consider the following expressions equivalent.

$$a = b \cdot c \cdot d$$
$$a = (b \cdot c) \cdot d$$
$$a = b\cdot(c\cdot d)$$

If a, b, c, and d are four matrices, then the order is most defiantly right to left, like so:

$$a = b \cdot c \cdot d$$
$$a = b \cdot (c \cdot d)$$

Since a real number is like a 1x1 matrix, is the first example an *exception to the rule* or am I *incorrect* in my first statement about the order of real number multiplication?

Probably should mention, err, it doesn't actually matter, since the answer is the same, but it is an interesting aspect to theory which I wanted to know.

Comment: Though I'm not particularly fond of the question, I just had to upvote for "most defiantly".

Comment: @AndreasBlass, thanks, I guess I have had that hammered into me by various OpenGL books

Answer (score 9):

Actually, matrix multiplication **is associative**, just as is scalar multiplication.

(Recall the properties of [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Properties_of_matrix_multiplication).)

So for $A$, expressed as the product of three matrices $B, C, D$  of appropriate dimension (i.e., such that matrix multiplication $BC$ and $CD$ is defined), we have that $$A = B\times (C\times D) = (B\times C) \times D$$
This means that we can indeed multiply two matrices: $B \times C$, and then right multiply this product by $D$ to obtain precisely the same matrix $A$ that we'd get if we perform $A = B\times (C \times D)$.

Remark: It is not the case that matrix multiplication is commutative, though, as is scalar multiplication of real numbers.

Comment: Needs another TU! +1

Answer (score 5):

Matrix multiplication is associative, so $(AB)C=A(BC)$ for compatible matrices $A,B,C$.  It is not, on the other hand, commutative.  That is, $AB\neq BA$ (assuming the latter multiplication can even be carried out).

Comment: You can find $A$ and $B$ so that $AB\not=BA$ but for some matrices, they are equal.

Comment: @xavierm02 you're right, I suppose I should have said that **in general**, $AB\neq BA$ for matrices $A$ and $B$.